# Не удаётся установить MongoDB под Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

Не удаётся установить MongoDB. Что я ни вводил, я ничего не могу с этим поделать.

```
Admin@DESKTOP-F3SQANN c:\xampp_7.3\htdocs\expressnails.ru
# composer install
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.

  Problem 1
    - mongodb/mongodb is locked to version 1.9.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.9.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.10.0 -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mongodb extension.
  Problem 2
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.9.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.10.0 -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mongodb extension.
    - jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.8 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.4 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.9.0].
    - jenssegers/mongodb is locked to version v3.6.8 and an update of this package was not requested.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp_7.3\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

У меня стоит PHP 7.3.29, а основная задача - достучаться до сайта и взглянуть на вёрстку. Возможно ли заставить PHP игноировать ошибки и отобразить статическую страницу или всё-таки можно как-то установить эти зависимости?

Comment: И не получится. [Был такой анекдот](https://www.anekdot.ru/id/-421000006/). И здесь то же самое. Ну НЕ УСТАНАВЛИВАЕТ композер программы на компьютере. Он устанавливает пхп скрипты. А про расширения пхп говорит тебе человеческим голосом: To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp_7.3\php\php.ini

Comment: Я делал это уже, но это только подсвечивает, что сам разрешил MongoDB, а его здесь и нет.

Comment: Если "здесь него нет", то значит расширение не установлено. Л - логика.

Comment: Окей, я понял. Мне просто надо найти в оф. сайте установщик MongoDB и установить. Верно я понял?

Comment: @Ипатьев, я только что установил MongoDB, скачав установщик .msi с их официального сайта, но никакого эффекта. В php.ini уже есть extension=mongodb.so. Что я не так делаю?

Comment: очевидно же что редактируете не тот php.ini

Comment: Но ведь консоль говорит мне о том, что в этом пути находится php.ini, я открыл по этому же пути этот файл и внёс нужные изменения. Разве есть ещё один php.ini? Сообщение ошибки - PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mongodb.so'

Comment: Теперь надо погуглить эту ошибку

Comment: Я уже окончательно растерялся. Я листаю те же страницы форумов в поисках ответа уже миллион раз. Может где-то надо найти mongodb.so?

Comment: Стоп. А при чем здесь вообще mongodb.so, если у вас виндоус?

Comment: А "те же" страницы листать не надо. Эта ошибка ведь совершенно другая. Надо выстроить простую  логику действий: видим ошибку, гуглим, исправляем. Видим следующую - гуглим, исправляем. Уже новую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно установить расширение `mongodb` для php вручную. Как правильно сообщает вам Composer, а также говорят вам комментариях, Composer не устанавливает расширения для PHP автоматически.

Само расширение нужно скачать с сайта [windows.php.net](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/mongodb/). Для PHP версии `7.3.29` подойдет актуальная на текущий момент версия расширения `1.9.2`.

При загрузки расширения `mongodb` вам нужно знать: 32 или 64-битная у вас версия PHP, а также она потокобезопасная или нет. Гипотетически, на этой версии XAMPP у вас должна быть 32-битная потокобезопасная версия PHP (x86, TS).

Чтобы узнать наверняка, вы можете выполнить следующую команду в консоли:

```
c:\xampp_7.3\php\php.exe -r "echo (PHP_INT_SIZE == 4 ? '32 bit' : '64 bit') . PHP_EOL;" && php -i | findstr Thread
```

В ответ вы получите примерно такой вывод:

```
32 bit
Thread Safety => enabled
```

Если у вас потокобезопасная 32-битная версия PHP 7.3, скачайте архив с соответствующим именем:

```
php_mongodb-1.9.2-7.3-ts-vc15-x86.zip
```

Затем распакуйте файлы `php_mongodb.dll` и `php_mongodb.pdb` в папку `C:\xampp_7.3\php\ext\` а потом отредактируйте файл `C:\xampp_7.3\php\php.ini` и добавьте в него строчку:

```
extension=mongodb
```

После всех манипуляций перезагрузите Apache.

Comment: Вау! После столь долгого времени благодаря вам я наконец смог запустить сайт. Всё работает! Спасибо вам большое за помощь и максимально полезный и подробный ответ. Он действительно мне помог. Награда будет выдана через 11 часов.